# Simulating an identity column within an insert trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table for logging that needs a log ID but I can't use an identity column because the log ID is part of a combo key.

```
create table StuffLogs
{
   StuffID int
   LogID int
   Note varchar(255)
}
```

There is a combo key for `StuffID` & `LogID`.

I want to build an insert trigger that computes the next LogID when inserting log records. I can do it for one record at a time (see below to see how `LogID` is computed), but that's not really effective, and I'm hoping there's a way to do this without cursors.

```
select @NextLogID = isnull(max(LogID),0)+1 
from StuffLogs where StuffID = (select StuffID from inserted)
```

The net result should allow me to insert any number of records into StuffLogs with the LogID column auto computed.

```
StuffID  LogID  Note
123      1      foo
123      2      bar
456      1      boo
789      1      hoo
```

Inserting another record using `StuffID: 123, Note: bop` will result in the following record:

```
StuffID  LogID  Note
123      3      bop
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is a rigid business reason that requires each LogID to be a sequence starting from 1 for each distinct StuffID, then just use an identity.  With an identity, you'll still be able to order rows properly with StuffID+LogID, but you'll not have the insert issues of trying to do it manually (concurrency, deadlocks, locking/blocking, slow inserts, etc.).

Comment: Just because it is part of a composite key doesn't mean it can't be an identity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Row_Number() Over( Order By LogId ) + MaxValue.LogId + 1
From inserted
    Cross Join ( Select Max(LogId)  As Id From StuffLogs ) As MaxValue
```

You would need to thoroughly test this and ensure that if two connections were inserting into the table at the same time that you do not get collisions on LogId.

Comment: You will probably want to wrap this into a BEGIN TRANSACTION ... END TRANSACTION, and possibly even SET TRANSACTION ISOLATIONLEVEL SERIALIZABLE to begin with - just to make sure no two connections can update at the same time and get the same new ID back

Comment: @marc_s - Agreed. That will obviously have some deleterious effects on concurrency.

Comment: > Select Max(Id) As Id From StuffLogs 

1. You find global maximum, but not for StuffID inserted.
2. Your query will not work when inserting more than one row at a time, for example:
insert into StuffLogs(staffid, not) values(123, 'a'), (123, 'b'),...

Comment: @msi77 - That's a typo on my part. It should actually be Max(LogId). In short, it should find the highest LogId in use. That will work for multiple values inserted as I'm taking the last used value and adding a value for each row in inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the LogId has a default value of NULL, so that it need not be supplied during insert statements, like it was an identity column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert ON dbo.StuffLogs
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
UPDATE #Inserted SET LogId = select max(LogId)+1 from StuffLogs where StuffId=[INSERTED].StuffId
```